# VS2010 bind implementation doesn't support move-only types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010, move-semantics

I've found that the following code doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2010 (but works fine in GCC):

```
using namespace std;
unique_ptr<string> up(new string("abc"));
auto bound = bind(&string::size, move(up));
bound();
```

The error I get is:

> 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Is it because the VS2010 bind implementation just doesn't support move only types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your guess is correct:  The Visual C++ 2010 implementation of `std::bind` is not move-aware.  See the bug report, ["std::bind and std::function are not move-aware."](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/649274/std-bind-and-std-function-are-not-move-aware)

This is fixed in the forthcoming version, Visual C++ 11.  The fix should be present in the Visual C++ Developer Preview that was released in September.